# Why am I getting a NullPointerException in the following code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This is code to sort the contents of an existing file:

```
public void sortFile(String fileName)throws IOException
{
    FileReader fin=new FileReader("C:\\File Handling\\"+fileName+".txt");
    BufferedReader bin=new BufferedReader(fin);

    String[] str=new String[100];

    int i=0;
    while((str[i]=bin.readLine())!=null)
        i++;

    Arrays.sort(str);  //getting a NullPointerException here

    FileWriter fout=new FileWriter("C:\\File Handling\\"+fileName+".txt");
    BufferedWriter bout=new BufferedWriter(fout);
    PrintWriter pout=new PrintWriter(bout);

    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        pout.println(str[i]);
}
```

However upon executing the code in an IDE, I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Can somebody please tell me why this is happening? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Which line are you getting exception?

Comment: at what line are you getting the error?

Comment: Your array may contain Strings which are initialized with `null`. When you try to sort them by the natural order using `Arrays.sort` internally something like `a.compareTo(b)`will be used. If `a`is `null`a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try:

```
Arrays.sort(str, 0, i);
```

The array contains null strings and these cause the NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The sort function of my program now works.

Answer (score 0):

It is just because you start by declaring a 100  positions array, then you fill JUST some (one per line, until file has lines) and then you scan all the 100 position.

As others already pointed out, first scan is performed by Arrays.sort() calling compare() on null elements when you arrive at a position i where

```
 str[i] == null
```

then you get you error because of calling str[i].compare() on the array item that is null.

To solve the problem you should save the count of how many lines you put in your array and then just sort/loop until that position.
BTW you already have it in the i variable when you are reading the file, just store it.

```
int i=0;
int lineNumber=0;
while((str[i]=bin.readLine())!=null) {
    lineNumber = i++;
}
```

PS Please use the parenthesis, they will help you a lot in reading and avoiding problems :)

Comment: This information is incorrect. It will print null when there are null elements. System.out.print functions print null ? "null" : obj.toString()

Comment: @nmore you are correct, I changed the answer leaving only how to solve the problem. And giving credit to others for the correct point.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining String array with 100 size beforehand, which by default initialized all 100 elements to null. Now if you say have 4 lines in your file, then rest 96 elements would be null and only 4 elements of yours would be initialized. And then when you sort that array you get NullPointerException.

You have two options here:

Either change from String array to List and use api like:

```
Collections.sort(...);//pass your list
```

OR Using array you could use api like:

```
Arrays.sort(String array, startIndex, end Index);
```

So here you could pass yoru array with 0 as start Index while i as end index. But you are wasting space unnecessarily here.